# How does Ubuntu know my native language?

Tags: language-support

I downloaded Ubuntu ISO and done a clean install.Upon booting it shows everything in my native language,Malayalam(language for Kerala state, India).I really wondered thinking how it happened.During installation I selected English as my default language.But how it knows I am from Kerala? Ubuntu is funny!!! I love it!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an internet connection during install:

```
wget -O - -q http://geoip.ubuntu.com/lookup
```

For me this results in ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Ip>???????</Ip>
<Status>OK</Status>
<CountryCode>NL</CountryCode>
<CountryCode3>NLD</CountryCode3>      
<CountryName>Netherlands</CountryName>
<RegionCode>05</RegionCode>
<RegionName>Limburg</RegionName>
<City>Roermond</City>
<ZipPostalCode></ZipPostalCode>
<Latitude>51.1927</Latitude>
<Longitude>5.9884</Longitude>
<AreaCode>0</AreaCode>
<TimeZone>Europe/Amsterdam</TimeZone>
</Response>
```

If you do no have one it will not show any default settings.

Not sure but if there is already a Ubuntu installed I would expect it to fetch those settings from the current installation too (ie. /etc/localtime) if there is not internet connection (not sure but seems logical to me ;) )

Comment: Revealing your IP in public like this is a bad idea if you're a gamer ;)

Comment: [It is not impossible](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=valve_linux_dampfnudeln). If you edit it within 5 minutes (like you did), no new history entry will be created.

Comment: I was offline for a while,could not answer u.U see I disconnected net during installation(just coz I was so excited to get in to 12.04) coz a net connection make it download something that I dont like during the process.Moreover I installed 12.04 from multisystem which made by this way http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/.The next thing I noted that when I started up installation it asked me lang for installation, the highlighted item was Malayalam but I selected English instead.I just ran the multisystem with Ubuntu and it also shows Malayalam.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP reveals instantly your location. The same applies for google, if you type google.com it will redirect you to your country's google page, unless you've clicked to 'Go to google.com in English'.

So I suspect this is how it's done.

Comment: hakermania, thnx for ur time. But u see I am here in Qatar,having my job.